# Rendering three components in pairs in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a todo application and I have 3 components and I want to render them in pairs. When I add todo in `TodoAdd` component I want to render `TodoNotDone` and `TodoAdd` components. When I mark a todo as done in the `TodoNotDone` component, I want to render the components `TodoNotDone` and `TodoDone`. How can I do it ? I am attaching the code and output for better understanding (Output added as link).

```
export default function Todo() {

const [todo, setTodo] = useState([])
const [todoDone, setTodoDone] = useState([])

return (
    <div >

        <Row className='Todo-container'>
            <Col span={8}></Col>
            <Col span={8}>
                <TodoHeader />  
                <TodoAdd setTodo={setTodo} />
                <Row className='Todo-container'>
                    <Col span={12}>
                        <TodoNotDone todos={todo} setTodoDone={setTodoDone} setTodo={setTodo} />
                    </Col>
                    <Col span={12}>
                        <TodoDone todoDone={todoDone} />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Col>
            <Col span={8}></Col>
        </Row>

    </div>
)}
```

[Output of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DS4h3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You created a todo items **list**, as represented in your state.

However you render just a single item, which doesn't allow updating each of the items separately.

I'd slightly rename the state variables, to better represent it being a list, then render each item separately:
(I did assume each item has a unique `id` and a `done` boolean variable)

```
const [todoNotDoneItems, setTodoNotDoneItems] = useState([])
const [todoDoneItems, setTodoDoneItems] = useState([])

function setToDoAsDone(id) {
    setTodoNotDoneItems((prev) => (
        prev.map((item) => (
            item.id === id
                ? { ...item, done: true }; // Or any other implementation
                : item
        ))
    );
}

return (
    <div >
        <Row className='Todo-container'>
            <Col span={8}></Col>
            <Col span={8}>
                <TodoHeader />  
                <TodoAdd setTodo={setTodo} />
                <Row className='Todo-container'>
                    <Col span={12}>
                        {
                            todoNotDoneItems.map((todoNotDoneItem) => (
                                <TodoNotDoneItem
                                    key={todoNotDoneItem.id}
                                    item={todoNotDoneItem}
                                    markAsDone={() => setToDoAsDone(todoNotDoneItem.id)}
                                />
                            )
                        }
                    </Col>
                    <Col span={12}>
                        {
                            todoDoneItems.map((todoDoneItem) => (
                                <TodoDoneItem
                                    key={todoDoneItem.id}
                                    item={todoDoneItem}
                                />
                            )
                        }
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Col>
            <Col span={8}></Col>
        </Row>

    </div>
)}
```